# How do you complete Robin's flurry attack challenge?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

There is a challenge that reads:

*As Robin, use a flurry attack to KO a Lv. 9 CPU in a 2-player battle. This must be done within 3 minutes, with spirits off, and without handicaps.*

I've tried for at least an hour to open this challenge, but nothing I do seems to be working. I assume by flurry attack they mean Robin's rapid jab attack, where he uses his wind tome. I've tried many things:

- KO the enemy on a stage with walk-off blast lines, such as the Boxing Ring.
- KO the enemy using the lava in The Great Cave Offensive.
- KO the enemy the regular way on a normal stage, KOing them when they have a high enough percentage.

None of it worked and I'm sure the match was over within 3 minutes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### You must fight a timed battle of length < 3 minutes

Looking at "walkthrough videos" (that really aren't too helpful) both [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzdKOtlib8I) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1vHTqWcmAo), it seems they've both used rule sets that set the match time to be less than 3 minutes. This is confirmed to be necessary in the comments:

> Just so everyone knows, I've tried this multiple times and it didn't work. I changed the time to 2:30 instead of 3:00 and it instantly worked. Give it a go if you've been having the same issue.
>
> - MiLo ChaelPez

So even 3 minute matches are too much!

In addition to this, I'd suggest fighting against a Jigglypuff, as Puff is very light and so will be launched further from your attacks and be killed sooner.

From another comment, it sounds like you can even get away with turning the launch rate up to 2.0x and still complete the challenge:

> what i did was i choose jigglypuff as the cpu and set the launch rate to 2.0, then i went to Dreamland and beat it there
>
> - DoggoTron

If you're having trouble actually doing the Rapid Jab, we actually have a question on just that (for this character too!) [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/342370/222207).

Comment: For me it worked with 3 minute battles.

Comment: Like inakilbss, I also unlocked this challenge with 3 minute battles. I fought against Kirby, since he is also light but seems less aggressive (and more easily readable) than Jigglypuff. Basically I just spammed my fully charged thunder projectile until he was at about 80%, then I did a few aerials to bring him to around 120%. I was able to KO him with the flurry attack at this point.

Comment: One comment on Reddit claimed that this challenge can also be completed in Sudden Death mode, and that made the challenge trivially easy. Haven't been able to verify it myself yet, as the first hit of the neutral jab always is enough to send the CPU flying.

Comment: @QuestionMarks to test that I'd suggest starting and holding the rapid jab while the CPU is approaching you (while they're still on the other side of the stage). I don't have a Switch with me to test at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: This should work with a 3:00 rule instead of 2:30. I've completed other challenges mentioning "within 3 minutes" that way, and according to [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a75gdn/help_with_challenge_board_what_exactly_is_robins/ecadkkx/), someone's completed the challenge with a 3:00 rule too.

Answer (score 0):

Stamina did not work for me. It seems that a stamina death doesn't count as a KO for this challenge.

Here are the rules I used:

- Stock battle: 1. I believed I had to win for it to count, so I wanted to end the battle as soon as I succeeded.
- Time: 3 minutes. Since the Challenge needed to be complete in 3 minutes, there's no point in a battle that takes longer.
- Spirits: Off. (Required.)
- Handicap: Off. (Required.)
- Stage Selection: Random.
- CPU: Level 9. I've failed several other challenge attempts because the CPU was the wrong level. It resets when you change the main game mode.
- Random stages: Final Destination only. This speeds up retries.
- Launch rate: 2x. More likely to die.
- Items: High. Black Hole only. (Credit to [this Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a75gdn/help_with_challenge_board_what_exactly_is_robins/ec0m1qm/))

I chose Donkey Kong as the enemy, as it is big and doesn't have projectiles.

Strategy: Wait for a Black Hole item, then toss it at the enemy and do flurries. It took several tries to set it up, but two flurries were enough to KO the opponent.

Comment: Someone submitted an edit to the launch rate: *"this however counts as a handicap, and if you use it, the challenge will be null and void"*. I rejected this edit because, as I wrote it, these were the rules I used to succeed, so these rules presumably work. It is possible that I misremembered the rules, or that a version changed the requirements, but the edit should probably be a comment or answer.